# Is there anyway to disable auto resolving concrete types in structuremap 4?

Tags: structuremap, structuremap4

Just a simple question. I am looking for a way to disable the auto resolving concrete types feature (as described below):

http://structuremap.github.io/resolving/requesting-a-concrete-type/

Is it possible ?